# When Web Page loads then pause and mute screen appears and after some time actual video screen appears. How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropbox, dropbox-api, youtube-javascript-api

1) This First Screen appears when Web Page loads. (Screen 1)

[image: First Image when Page loads]

2) After few seconds of above Screen this Screen Comes. (Screen 2)

[image: Second Image after some seconds]

Why this Screen 1 comes? How should I remove that bug?
I just want that after Web page load Screen 2 (Video) should appear/display.

How Can I do this? I am new with this Video embedding so please help.

My code for reference :

```
dropboxVideo : function(){
    new_video = document.createElement('video');
    new_video.setAttribute('controls','true');
    new_video.setAttribute('preload','none');//autoPlay: false, 'preload':'auto'
    video = document.getElementById('RIZfC358yRk').appendChild(new_video);
    source = document.createElement('source');  
    source.setAttribute('src','https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87532981/Ella%20May%20and%20the%20Wishing%20Stone%20By%20Cary%20Fagan.mp4');
    video.appendChild(source);
    video.load();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a built in solution but it seems that there's none.
So I coded Something that is the result of what you are looking for:

```
    <div id="videoelt" style="display:none" ></div>
<script>
 function dropboxVideo (){
    var videoElt = document.getElementById('videoelt');
    new_video = document.createElement('video');
    new_video.setAttribute('controls','true');
    //new_video.setAttribute('preload','none');//autoPlay: false, 'preload':'auto'
    new_video.setAttribute('autoplay','true');//autoPlay: false, 'preload':'auto'

    //new_video.setAttribute('poster','foo.jpg');
    source = document.createElement('source');  
    source.setAttribute('src','https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87532981/Ella%20May%20and%20the%20Wishing%20Stone%20By%20Cary%20Fagan.mp4');
    new_video.appendChild(source);
    videoElt.appendChild(new_video);

    new_video.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) { 
        videoElt.style.display = '';
    }); 
}

dropboxVideo();
</script>
```

The video element has events that you can listen to, the 'canplay' fits the moment it starts.
So I hidden the video control until is ready and then I displayed it.
Another option that you can use the 'poster' attribute of the video element. Put some image that will be displayed for hinting what's about to played.

Comment: Thank you. new_video.setAttribute('poster','foo.jpg'); this is good as per my requirement. canplay is also good but I do not to hide div. I will try to add waiting image till video load and after that other image.

Comment: I think that the poster is enough as a solution, but anyway I thought it might be worth checking if possible ;-)

Comment: Yes I checked with both options thanks for this. In poster option I am added waiting image and when video is ready to play then different image, so it looks nice.